# Efficient Way to Read/Write Vectors to File

Tags: c++, file, vector, armadillo

Overview: After several days of research, I have been unable to find a fast, efficient way to write/read a vector to/from a file. The majority of answers that I have seen involve pushing/popping each individual element in/out of the file. This is incredibly time consuming as the number of elements increase. Additionally, I have been unable to find an attempt at an answer to my *specific* problem. So please, make sure that your solution will work for my *specific* circumstance (i.e. read the *entire* question).

My Problem: I have a really large data structure that contains pixel information about images. There are 60,000 images with 784 pixels each. Each picture is an image of a handwritten digit. So, in addition to the 60,000 * 784 pixels, I need to include a label so I know which digit the image represents. The label that I use, which is necessary when looked at in the scope of the entire project, is a vector of 10 possibilities, representing a 0, 1, 2 ... 9, only one of which contains a '1'/'true' while the rest are '0'/'false'. Additionally, this data structure, due to linear algebra requirements throughout the rest of the project, requires that the information be stored in a 'Col' structure utilized in the Armadillo Linear Algebra Library. So, the structure that I wish to save/read in/from a file is declared as `std::vector<std::vector<arma::Col<double>>>`.

Here is the function that I am using to save the data right now, to give context:

```
void SaveTrainingData(vector<vector<Col<double>>> trainingData) //format: trainingData[60000][2][784, 10]
{
    ofstream ofile("VectorizedTrainingData.dat", ios::binary);

    for (int i = 0; i < trainingData.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < trainingData[i].size(); j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < trainingData[i][j].size(); k++)
                ofile.write((char *)&trainingData[i][j][k], sizeof(double));
}
```

If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to ask! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `void SaveTrainingData(vector<vector<Col<double>>> trainingData)` If you didn't pass vector by value, things might be sped up on just the function call alone.  Also, are you running this with optimizations enabled or a "debug" unoptimized version of your program?  Also, note that disk I/O is a tough thing to optimize in some respects, since a lot of it comes down to the disk's performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to look up documentation on this Armadillo library, but it appears like `Col` is a contiguous, dense vector class. We can depend on the contiguous representation to eliminate a nested loop, like so:

```
// format: trainingData[60000][2][784, 10]
void SaveTrainingData(const vector<vector<Col<double>>>& trainingData) 
{
    ofstream ofile("VectorizedTrainingData.dat", ios::binary);

    const int numImages = trainingData.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
    {
        const vector<Col<double>>& img = trainingData[i];
        const int numCols = img.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
        {
            const Col<double>& col = img[j];
            ofile.write((char*)&col[0], col.size()*sizeof(double));
        }
    }
}
```

The reduced frequency in calls to `write` from one element in a column to a whole column may already help a bit.

It may be worth measuring this to make sure you're actually more I/O bound instead of memory bound. It's a little tricky with the potential memory fragmentation involving all these vectors of vectors of columns.

If the size of the inner vector is always the same (which seems to be the case with every image being 784 pixels), for example, you might be able to get potentially better results with a contiguous `vector<Col>`, or this:

```
struct Image
{
     Col pixels[768];
};
...
vector<Image> trainingData;
```

... or something like that. . I couldn't quite follow how the linear algebra ties in to the image rep, but hopefully this gives an idea.

Comment: Thanks so much! This will certainly help me out a lot. And the linear algebra stuff ties into the rest of the project later on, so it is not really relevant here, just necessary for the rest of the program.

Comment: Do you have any additional input when it comes to reading the file?

Comment: @Rob Reading should be pretty symmetrical with writing -- you can do pretty much the same thing. Don't think there's anything extra we could do there -- pretty much straight I/O of binary data.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Armadillo, but since a Col is a 1xN matrix and that should be stored linearly, you can get rid of the `k` loop and write out the entire column in one go:

```
ofile.write((char *)&trainingData[i][j][0], sizeof(double) * trainingData[i][j].size());
```

If that won't work, copy the elements from the Col to a local vector then write those out to the file (since the file operation will be much slower than copying some doubles around).

You probably also want to write out the size of your vector before writing all your elements so you know how many there are to read in.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out! Also, I usually write the size of the vector into the file before the elements, but this time, in the effort to eliminate as much unnecessary data as possible (since I know the sizes of all the vectors ahead of time), I removed it.